# prettyPhoto script not called no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I was trying to add popup helpers on my page using prettyPhoto ( [link](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) ) - link to my page ( [link2](http://ntt.vipserv.org/artifact/) ). So I've included what needed, copied some code from the demo and unfortunately nothing happens. Script is in no way executed. I've tried removing all other imports but still nothing. What can be other causes to prevent script from running/loading properly?

Comment: are you getting any errors in firebug?? check if all the needed scripts download or not through firebug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this page which explains how to set it up:

- http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/

You have several problems. First is that you haven't called the code that you use to start the library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
    });
</script>
```

Second is that you are putting [inline] in your rel where you dont need to:

```
rel="prettyPhoto[inline]"
```

should just be

```
rel="prettyPhoto"
```

Comment: actually he has id='howto' which is what it would look for, no hash :)

Comment: oops :) ive removed it from my reply